# How to update from select query that using opendatasource?

Tags: sql, subquery

What I am trying to achieve is to update the value of "Flag" in a column based on data from another.

```
UPDATE TableUser
SET
TableUser.Flag = DATA.Flag
FROM
(
    SELECT userID, Flag FROM 
    (
        SELECT userID, Flag from userID
        EXCEPT
        SELECT userID, Flag
        FROM OPENDATASOURCE('sqloledb', 'Data Source=192.168.1.2;user id=admin;password=123456').officeDB.dbo.TableUser
    ) DATA
) WHERE DATA.userID = TableUser.userID
```

I think the problem is that my opendatasource is not initializing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On which DBMS are you trying to achieve that ?

Comment: Are you having the issue only when running the update or is it failing when you are trying the OPENDATASOURCE subquery separately? Please try to localise the issue first so as to make the question  specific enough without superfluous details.